# Parsing xml in python - don't understand the DOM

Tags: python, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup

I've been reading up on parsing xml with python all day, but looking at the site i need to extract data on, i'm not sure if i'm barking up the wrong tree.  Basically i want to get the 13-digit barcodes from a supermarket website (found in the name of the images).  For example:

http://www.tesco.com/groceries/SpecialOffers/SpecialOfferDetail/Default.aspx?promoId=A31033985

has 11 items and 11 images, the barcode for the first item is 0000003235676.  However when i look at the page source (i assume this is the best way to extract all of the barcodes in one go with python, urllib and beautifulsoup) all of the barcodes are on one line (line 12) however the data doesn't seem to be structured as i would expect in terms of elements and attributes.

```
    new TESCO.sites.UI.entities.Product({name:"Lb Mens Mattifying Dust 7G",xsiType:"QuantityOnlyProduct",productId:"275303365",baseProductId:"72617958",quantity:1,isPermanentlyUnavailable:true,imageURL:"http://img.tesco.com/Groceries/pi/805/5021320051805/IDShot_90x90.jpg",maxQuantity:99,maxGroupQuantity:0,bulkBuyLimitGroupId:"",increment:1,price:2.5,abbr:"g",unitPrice:3.58,catchWeight:"0",shelfName:"Mens Styling",superdepartment:"Health & Beauty",superdepartmentID:"TO_1448953606"});
new TESCO.sites.UI.entities.Product({name:"Lb Mens Thickening Shampoo 250Ml",xsiType:"QuantityOnlyProduct",productId:"275301223",baseProductId:"72617751",quantity:1,isPermanentlyUnavailable:true,imageURL:"http://img.tesco.com/Groceries/pi/225/5021320051225/IDShot_90x90.jpg",maxQuantity:99,maxGroupQuantity:0,bulkBuyLimitGroupId:"",increment:1,price:2.5,abbr:"ml",unitPrice:1,catchWeight:"0",shelfName:"Mens Shampoo ",superdepartment:"Health & Beauty",superdepartmentID:"TO_1448953606"});
new TESCO.sites.UI.entities.Product({name:"Lb Mens Sculpting Puty 75Ml",xsiType:"QuantityOnlyProduct",productId:"275301557",baseProductId:"72617906",quantity:1,isPermanentlyUnavailable:true,imageURL:"http://img.tesco.com/Groceries/pi/287/5021320051287/IDShot_90x90.jpg",maxQuantity:99,maxGroupQuantity:0,bulkBuyLimitGroupId:"",increment:1,price:2.5,abbr:"ml",unitPrice:3.34,catchWeight:"0",shelfName:"Pastes, Putty, Gums, Pomades",superdepartment:"Health & Beauty",superdepartmentID:"TO_1448953606"});
```

Maybe something like BeautifulSoup is overkill?  I understand the DOM tree is not the same thing as the raw source, but why are they so different - when i go to inspect element in firefox the data seems structured as i would expect.

Apologies if this comes across as totally stupid, thanks in advance.

Comment: on mentioned page there is element with id `h-278680465`. what is it's barcode?

Comment: There's no XML here to parse; you're looking at JavaScript source embedded in an HTML page.

Comment: I think you need to clarify whether your problem is getting the javascript bits you show (which is a dom/html parsing issue), or if you need to figure out how to parse the data you show.

Comment: Thanks Marcin, I think my problem is the former - scraping the Javascript, i assume the rest would just be regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the barcode is not given in the HTML as structured data; it only appears embedded as part of a URL. So we'll need to isolate the URL and then pick off the barcode with string manipulation:

```
import urllib2
import bs4 as bs
import re
import urlparse

url = 'http://www.tesco.com/groceries/SpecialOffers/SpecialOfferDetail/Default.aspx?promoId=A31033985'

response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
content = response.read()
# with open('/tmp/test.html', 'w') as f:
#     f.write(content)
# Useful for debugging off-line:
# with open('/tmp/test.html', 'r') as f:
#     content = f.read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(content)
barcodes = set()
for tag in soup.find_all('img', {'src': re.compile(r'/pi/')}):
    href = tag['src']
    scheme, netloc, path, query, fragment = urlparse.urlsplit(href)
    barcodes.add(path.split('\\')[1])

print(barcodes)
```

yields

```
set(['0000003222737', '0000010039670', '0000010036297', '0000010008393', '0000003050453', '0000010062951', '0000003239438', '0000010078402', '0000010016312', '0000003235676', '0000003203132'])
```

Comment: I should've specified the barcodes are 13 digits, so in <img class=" " width="90" height="90" alt="" src="http://img.tesco.com/Groceries/pi/676/0000003235676/IDShot_90x90.jpg"></img> is the 0000003235676 bit.  I was hoping it would be in the same place as the productId, and was gunning for an answer like you provided, cheers anyway!

Comment: Okay, I've edit the post; the technique is essentially the same.

Comment: This is brilliant, thanks a lot!  (although i feel like i've cheated lol)

Answer (score 1):

As your site uses javascript to format its content, You might find useful switching from urllib to a tool like [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/). That way you can crawl pages as they render for a real user with a web browser. This [github project](https://github.com/cmwslw/selenium-crawler) seems to solve your task.

Other option will be filtering out json data from page javascript scripts and getting data directly from there.

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising.